# How do I add data to the Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I cannot add any data on the Firebase Realtime Database. Database connections are ok but I cannot add any data. When I click to button, add to data on my database.

MainActivity.java - codes

```
        private FirebaseDatabase database;
        private DatabaseReference dbRef;
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String plan,note,date,time,remb,eventId;
                plan = etplan.getText().toString();
                note = etnote.getText().toString();
                date = etdate.getText().toString();
                time = ettime.getText().toString();

                if (remember.isChecked()==true){
                    remb= "true";
                }
                else{
                    remb = "false";
                }
                database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                dbRef = database.getReference("events");
                eventId = dbRef.push().getKey();
                event = new Events(plan,note,date,time,remb);
                dbRef.child(eventId).setValue(event);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Events Added SUCCESSFULLY!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Events.java - codes

```
public class Events {
    String plan;
    String note;
    String date;
    String time;
    String remb;

    public Events(){

    }

    public Events(String plan, String note, String date, String time, String remb){
        this.plan=plan;
        this.note=note;
        this.date=date;
        this.time=time;
        this.remb=remb;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in run :
at com.cdirect.agenda.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:118)

this code:

```
dbRef.child(eventId).setValue(event);
```

and before this code of eventID (is String)

```
eventId = dbRef.push().getKey().toString();
```

Comment: You're not checking for errors on the call to setValue.  It could be failing and you'd never know why.

Comment: So what is the solution for this? @DougStevenson

Comment: Check for errors as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback).

Comment: Have you tried to check for errors, as Doug mentioned in his comment?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add a listener to `setValue(event)` method like this:

```
dbRef.child(eventId).setValue(event)
     .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                 } else {
                 Toast.makeText(this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
      }
```

Now `task.getException().getMessage()` will let you know what the actual problem is about saving your event data.

Also, don't forget to check the database rules that read and write is set to `true`.

Comment: It's not a good idea to blindly set security rules to true.  That's potentially a big security problem, and we never recommend that without explaining the caveats.

Comment: You are totally right but I thought maybe at the time of creating database, he set both read write to false instead of defining any auth conditions. Thanks for your concern! :)

Comment: I created database with test mode and switched "true"  to  read and write rules.